# Post to Wordpress from Facebook

Tags: facebook, wordpress, cross-posting

I've got a client who is more familiar and confident with the facebook intefrace and would like have her posts from Facebook Business page be autoposted on her Wordpress blog.

Any hints on how to achieve this.

I understand the benefits of getting her using Worpress, but at this stage the lack of WYSIWYG in the WordPress app is holding her back.

Any suggestions of plugins to take Facebook posts to Wordpress would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook does not yet provide [real-time updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) for `stream` posts on pages, so you'll need to do something like this:

Set up a cron job to call a script on schedule (once per hour or day probably) that:

1. Makes an API call to her page's `feed` to see if any new posts were made since the last poll.
2. If data is returned, loop through the results and create a new WP post for each FB post.

Just make sure there aren't any plugins installed on WP that autopost to FB.

I haven't ever seen a plugin like this before. There are some plugins out there that make editing Wordpress more user-friendly like [Front End Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/). This might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

get the rss feed url of your fb page and put it into the feedwordpress plugin